# Brightness doesn't change. But, sleeping the computer and coming back, works

Tags: kde, kde-4, brightness, suspend

I can't change my brightness on my laptop and I would like a help to solve this problem.

Using `kcmshell4 kgamma` I can change the constrast. But using `xbacklight` nothing happens.

If I put

> xbacklight -get

I got a value, for example, `86.666667`, but when I try

> xbacklight -dec 40

Nothing happens.

The strange thing is that commands above (`xbacklight -dec 40`) can work if I suspend my session and reopen it again.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the

> xbacklight -set

function.